# Is it possible to login from a cell phone

Tags: login-screen, two-factor-authentication

I want to login to UI from another device. Google authentication satisfies me but it does not work perfectly. I would like to work it as the finger login works. I am working on HP and I have problems with it. I am investigating the [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-multi-factor-authentication-on-ubuntu-18-04) Does another solution exist?

Comment: Please update your question: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using the desktop or the server? What do you mean by "login from a cell phone?" Do you want to use the cell phone as an authenticating device when you are very close to the computer, or do you want to see and interact with the Ubuntu desktop/server using the cell phone screen from very far away?

Comment: You can certainly ssh in from a cell phone, I do that all the time.